# how to fix the flutter doctor issue "'dart' on your path resolves to " Windows pc?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have upgraded the flutter latest with the command flutter upgrade, after upgrading now flutter doctor shows the warning (below)

*Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to E:\Program Files\Android\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at E:\Program Files\Android\flutter. Consider adding E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\bin to the front of your path.*

anyone can help me ?

i tried by downloading flutter zip and replace the current flutter folder, but still the same happens !

Answer (score 4):

For Mac and linux users having the same issue,
Instead of adding the `/path/to/flutter` to the end of the `$PATH` variable add it to the beginning. So it should be `PATH="/path/to/flutter:$PATH"`. See [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115651#issuecomment-1409619007) for explanation.

Comment: This answer fixed it for me on MacOS

Answer (score 3):

1- go to E:\Program Files\Android\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe

2- cut "dart-sdk" folder

3- go to E:\Program Files\Android\flutter\bin

4- then Paste the "dart-sdk" folder inside it

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 in my case

- My project was in

  C:\Users\Oleksii\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterProjects\monitoring\flutter

[image: Android sScreenshot]

- I just moved `FlutterProjects` to `flutter` folder:

  C:\Users\Oleksii\flutter\FlutterProjects\monitoring>

[image: Android sScreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you do environmental and system variables edits and problem still occur. Simple and easy way to solve this problem check the known but actually wrong location of flutter document, there were a 0kb flutter doc for me. I deleted it then everything become well!